# How to call properties file from another properties file using Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm working on a command-line Java application using Spring. I have multiple properties files stored in different locations and one properties file containing the path for all those properties. I'm using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, to read properties containing the locations of different properties files. I'm not sure of the best way of handling multiple properties.

The application works like this: I will pass the path for first properties file using JVM command -Dmypath=parent.properties. The properties file will look like this:

```
child1=/location1/child1.properties

child2=/location2/child2.properties
```

so on

My Parent properties configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="parentProperty" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>                
            <value>${mypath}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The child1 configuration looks:

```
<bean id="child1Property" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>                
            <value>${child1}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now when I call child1 it fails to load the properties.

Answer (score 1):

I have load the parent property file first and then set the particular child1 and child2 variable in system environment variable and load from system environment variable. and its working fine.

code :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${mypath}/*.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

<bean id="systemPrereqs" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" value="#{@systemProperties}" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="putAll" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <!-- The new Properties -->
            <util:properties>
                <prop key="LOG_LOCATION">${log.location}</prop>
                <prop key="child1">${child1}</prop>
            </util:properties>
        </property>
    </bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="file:#{systemProperties['child1']}/*.sql" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution order of `BeanFactoryPostProcessors` such as `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` can be set by setting the property `"order"`(see [Ordered](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html)). By setting the execution priority of `parentProperty` higher that that of `child1Property` you can ensure that `parentProperty` runs first, configuring the value of `${child1}`.

Comment: I have tried by setting the order="1" parameter in parentProperty and also tried by adding depends-on="parentProperty" but it still fails <bean id="child1Property" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" depends-on="parentProperty">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>                
            <value>${child1}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

Comment: Looking again at your configuration the placeholder ${mypath} needs to be resolved for the parentProperty to load. You will need to either use another PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to resolve this placeholder (setting systemsPropertiesMode to use system properties) or provide the path to this properties file in another way.

Comment: When I run my application. My parentProperty is able to read all properties from the file specified in ${myfile}. I am able to read the properties other than file location. But I am trying to read property containing file location it is unable to load the file. It says FileNotFoundException for resource ${child1}

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to load the properties from the classpath, where the locations are included in your classpath, instead of in a file, and then the following will load all your property files.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: My application has requirement "not to place properties file in the classpath".